# Perfomance issues in MVC applciation with Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, view, asp.net-mvc-5, edmx

> I have one concern.
> I already created Views and I called every view in the EDMX file. Now I have a problem with performance.
> So, I thought I can remove all views from the edmx file and I will add a Stored procedure.
> I will call View into a stored procedure.
> Can it improve the performance?

```
 public (IList<TableView>, int) Get(Expression<Func<TableView, bool>> expression)
    {
IList<TableView> data = new List<TableView>(); int count = 0;
        using (Container context = new Container())
            {
                var query = context.TableView.Where(expression);
                count  = query.Count();
                query = query.OrderByQuery("Name", "Asc");
                data  = query.Paging(1,15);
                return (data,count);
            }
    }
```

Comment: Unlikely, if the view is slow that tends to imply you have a poorly performing query. Putting it inside a stored procedure won't change how it performs unless you change the logic. You should investigate the cause of the poor performance, the execution plans are a good place to start.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the position of the performance bottleneck. If you are having a very big data set from the view before filtering, using a stored procedure may help. Although the filtering usually could be also handled with Linq queries even without using sp.
I can recommend you putting you time in database optimizations for better index definitions and better queries that build up your view. To start take advantage of [Database Engine Tuning adviser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/start-and-use-the-database-engine-tuning-advisor?view=sql-server-ver16) and Sql Server Profiler.